# Kunneth formula for cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Why I can use Kunneth formula to say that
$H^{*}(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty} \times \mathbb{C}P^{\infty})= \mathbb{C}[x_{1}] \otimes \mathbb{C}[x_{2}]$?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\mathbb C[x_1]$ and not $\mathbb Z[x_1]$? Are you sure you mean "Why..." and not "How..."?

Comment: Yes, I take coefficients of cohomology in $\mathbb{C}$. Also how satisfies my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement of the Kunneth formula from Hatcher is

> The cross product $H^*(X; R) \otimes_R H^*(Y; R)$ is an isomorphism of rings if X and Y are CW complexes and $H^k(Y; R)$ is a finitely-generated free $R$-module for all $k$.

$\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is (homeomorphic to...) a CW complex; you can find a description of the entire structure in Hatcher's *Vector Bundles* or Milnor's *Characteristic Classes* (and probably many other books).  For any $k$, $H^k(\mathbb{C}P^\infty; \mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic either to $0$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  So the product $\mathbb{C}P^\infty \times \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ satisfies the hypotheses.

Working over $\mathbb{C}$, we immediately have $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty \times \mathbb{C}P^\infty; \mathbb{C}) \simeq H^*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty) \otimes_\mathbb{C} H^*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty) \simeq \mathbb{C}[x] \otimes \mathbb{C}[y]$, where $x$ and $y$ are the generators of each copy of $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^\infty; \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: very nice answer!

Comment: But from Hilbert basis theorem we have that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is finitely-generate as $\mathbb{C}$-module. So can I apply kunnet formula directly for $H^{*}(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}) \simeq \mathbb{C}[x]$...

Comment: @ArthurStuart Sure.  I stuck to the exact statement of the Kunneth Formula above, so I verified the hypotheses to the letter.

Comment: @ArthurStuart Moreover, a submodule of a finitely-generated module need not be finitely-generated, so I guess in principle you could run into trouble.  Certainly everything works fine with coefficients over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.  If you had some reason to compute cohomology with coefficients in a non-Noetherian ring, you'd have to check that each $H^k$ is finitely-generated separately.